# Linking to a user profile in wp user query

Tags: wordpress, loops

Im trying to create a staff directory to show all WP users to then allow you to click through and view their profile, similar to a standard custom post loop and then viewing a the single-{customPost}.php.

Below is the loop i have for my users but and iv created my template for the loop, but am struggling how to output the link to click through to view the user profile?

```
<?php

    // WP_User_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'id',
    );

    // The User Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // The User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>
        <li><a href="">User Name</a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

Try passing $user_ID global variable to function as following,

```
<?php 
  global $user_ID;
  if ( get_the_author_meta('user_url',$user_ID) ) : // If a user has filled out their decscription show a bio on their entries 
?>
  <a class="meta-website" href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url',$user_ID); ?>">Author's Website</a>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried that but no luck. Below is what i have but nothing shows:

`<?php $users_id = $user->id;
the_author_meta( 'user_url', $users_id ); ?>`

Comment: Have you checked $users_id have id of user?

Comment: Yes iv tried other meta values such as first_name and user_email and they display correctly but nothing for url

Comment: Can you try something like this, <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->id ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'user_url', $user->id ); ?></a>

Comment: Yes that seems to work now. Its taking me to /author/{{authorsname}}. Although im getting a page cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Prabu this is solved. The below worked for me:

```
<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->id ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'user_url', $user->id ); ?></a>
```

I was then getting an issue with the single author page throwing up a 404 but can see this is a permalink issue.

Comment: if the answer is correct you shouldn't post as answer you just click an up arrow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer